# Why is the dot product of these two vectors 6 (MIT OCW Multivariable Calculus)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a question from MIT OCW 18.02 Mutivariable calculus:

[image]

The answer expresses the dot product of the position vector and the normal vector of the plane as 6 and I don't understand why. Should the dot product be 0?

[image]

Comment: The dot product would only be zero if $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{N}$ are orthogonal (i.e at right angles). There is nothing in the question that specifies this to be the case. The formula for a plane (with position vector $\vec{r}$) is $$(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{0}) \cdot \vec{n} = 0 \implies \vec{r} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{r}_{0} \cdot \vec{n}$$ and comparing with the equation $$4x - 3y - 2z = 6$$ we find ...

Comment: Oh right. I get it now